# conditional statement based on terms

Tags: taxonomy, terms

I was wondering if someone could help me out. I have created a custom query to retrieve in a custom single.php to retrieve posts which have the same custom taxonomy term and display them. here is the query:

```
    <?php  
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'customtaxonomy' );
    if($terms){
      // post has course_type terms attached
      $product_terms = array();
      foreach ($terms as $term){
       $product_terms[] = $term->slug;
      }

     $original_query = $wp_query;
     $wp_query = null;
     $wp_query = new WP_Query( array(
     'post_type' => 'customposttype',
     'tax_query' => array(
      array(
     'taxonomy' => 'customtaxonomy',
     'field' => 'slug',
     'terms' => $customtaxonomy_terms, //the taxonomy terms I'd like to dynamically query
     'posts_per_page' => '6'
        ),
      ),
      'orderby' => 'title',
      'order' => 'ASC'
      ) );



if ( have_posts() ): ?>


//display what you want in loop here.



<?php endwhile; ?>
```

within that query i would like to have a multiple conditional statement so that if a term='term 1'display specific image.

```
<?php

        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            if($term->name == 'customtermincustomtaxonomy') {
               show image
            }
        }
 ?>
```

I know i could easy use a if/else statement but that would only allow me to have 2 conditions. I know I should use an else if statement but i have not used php in a while and am having some problems formatting it. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Switch statement](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php).

```
switch ($term->name) {
    case 'customtermincustomtaxonomy':
        // ...
        break;
    case 'anotherterm':
        // ...
        break;
    case 'somethingelse':
        // ...
        break;
}
```

Comment: totally forgot about that thanks lol. I appreciate it!